# VBA issue with dates

Tags: vba, excel

I need to apply an autofilter to select data within a certain date range. Also the date range are strings. The code works fine except it has actually changed the date to the american format so 6 Feb 2015 is now June 2 2015.

```
Dim mindate, maxdate, fixedmindate, fixedmaxdate As String

mindate = "060215"
maxdate = "120215"

fixedmindate = DateSerial(Right(mindate, 2), Mid(mindate, 3, 2), Left(mindate, 2))
fixedmaxdate = DateSerial(Right(maxdate, 2), Mid(maxdate, 3, 2), Left(maxdate, 2))
Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CQ" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="CHECK"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CQ" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:=">=" & fixedmindate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & fixedmaxdate
```

Answer (score 0):

This might have happened due to 'Regional formatting problem'

Change number format of dates in excelsheet from 'date' format category to 'text'; 
save it. After Saving run the VBA Code. Now check whether the date format is 'text' or changed back to 'date'.

If it has changed back to 'date' try to fix it as 'text'

If it's 'text'; Correct the erroneous date cells and save the excel sheet. This will make dates not to change automatically to American Format.

(You can confirm it by running the VBA code again)